# Why I can't open any onion link on TOR?

Tags: onion-services, windows, onion-routing

I am not able to open any .onion link on my Tor browser, I tried everything but don't understand what I missed. I also tried to open https://facebookcorewwwi.onion/ but I can't.

Please help me and guide me if there is any setting or any other functions where I can use onion links

Answer (score 0):

This is a v2 onion service address, and v2 onion services aren't supported anymore. You must use a v3 onion service address instead. You can read more here: https://support.torproject.org/onionservices/#onionservices_v2-deprecation

The correct onion service address for Facebook is now: [facebookwkhpilnemxj7asaniu7vnjjbiltxjqhye3mhbshg7kx5tfyd.onion](https://facebookwkhpilnemxj7asaniu7vnjjbiltxjqhye3mhbshg7kx5tfyd.onion) (see https://www.facebook.com/onion-service)